# SQL Injection in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, sql-injection

I am using hibernate and I need to replace this query to remove SQL injection.

```
strQry = "FROM xxxx bob WHERE bob.brkxxxId ='" + brkxxxId + "' AND bob.xxxUser ='" + loginUserxxxId + "'";
i = session.delete(strQry);
```

I rewrote this query like this:

```
    session = getSession();
   strQry = "FROM xxxxbob bob WHERE bob.brkxxxId = :param1 AND bob.xxxUser = :param2";


        Query bobQuery = session.createQuery(strQry);
        bobQuery.setParameter("param1", brkxxxId);
        bobQuery.setParameter("param2", xxxUserTaxId);

        java.util.List bobList = bobQuery.list();
      java.util.Iterator bobI1 = bobList.listIterator();
     while (bobI1.hasNext()){
                mapCache = (BOBMapCache) bobI1.next();
                session.delete(mapCache);
            }
```

Its returning null when selecting list even if the db contains values. I have no idea whats wrong.

Comment: why cant you say 'delete bob where bob.brkid=... ' like this? http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/batch.html#batch-direct

Comment: @Zeus I have checked this. but there is no exexuteUpdate() command in hibernate2

Answer (score 0):

Hi after looking are code i found when your rewrote your HQL, you forgot to create aliase for the the entity

```
session = getSession();
strQry = "FROM xxxxbob WHERE bob.brkxxxId = :param1 AND bob.xxxUser = :param2";
```

Please correct the HQL to

```
session = getSession();
strQry = "FROM xxxxbob bob WHERE bob.brkxxxId = :param1 AND bob.xxxUser = :param2";
```

I again checked it

```
        Query bobQuery = session.createQuery(strQry);
        bobQuery.setParameter("param1", brkxxxId);
        bobQuery.setParameter("param2", xxxUserTaxId);
```

You are missing following line of code in your code please correct it

```
    entityManager.createQuery(bobQuery).getResultList();
```

Initializing the entity manager

```
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();   //Transaction began
    try {
    List list=session.createQuery(bobQuery).list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();   //Transaction committed 
    Iterator iterator= list.iterator();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rahul actually I missed to add the alias. Still I am getting the result as null.

Comment: Hibernate created SQL in the logs for the HQL you have return...please check your logs and try to run that SQL manually generated by the hibernate..see results are coming or not..

Comment: Yes it is fetching correctly when I manually ran the query. Also I found that without using parameter, hibernate fetches the query but I need to avoid that

Comment: i have updated my previous answer you are missing : - entityManager.createQuery(bobQuery).getResultList();

Comment: please check my previous answer i have posted the entity initialization code

Comment: thanks for the reply man.. But I use Hibernate session manager instead of Entity manager..